# How to implement relationship between Petitions and User model in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, entity-relationship

I am wondering what is the best way to model a relationship between petitions and users in Ruby on Rails.
Here are the constraints

-a user own a petition

-a user create a petition

-one user can be the author of a petition

-all the users can sign a petition

Is this a polymorphism case?

Answer (score 2):

The petition can simply belong to the user that created it using the normal has_many and belongs_to relationship definitions.  Then use a HABTM table to track the signers.

For the User class I would define...

```
  has_many :created_petitions, :class_name => 'Petition', :foreign_key => 'creator_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :signed_petitions, :class_name => 'Petition', :association_foreign_key => 'signer_id'
```

And for the Petition class I would define...

```
   belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User'
   has_and_belongs_to_many :signers, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'signer_id'
```

Then the migration would be...

```
create_table :petitions_signers, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :petition_id
  t.integer :signer_id
end

add_column :petitions, :creator_id, :integer
```

Comment: I'd give the intermediary table a name, like signatures, and then use has_many :through to connect the users to the signed petitions

Comment: If additional data needed to be attached to the act of signing the petition (such as the date it was signed, which seems reasonable), then, yes, using a :through model would be my choice as well.  However, if no other data needs to be tracked (and fenec didn't indicate there was), then I believe an HABTM relationship is more efficient and results in faster code.

Comment: well now that you talk about it , it think that the signature date is very important. i would use :through.You guys are awesome thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism is when you're dealing with relationships between one entity and a number of unrelated entities. If it's between one entity and a number of similar entities, you may want to use STI instead.

Since you're talking about a simple User to Petition relationship, there's no reason to worry about polymorphism. What you need is a User model, a Petition model, and a UserPetition join model that records information about what their relationship to the petition is, such as creator or signer.